# Changing current attribute of HTML,from where the function gets called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JavaScript to build a dynamic HTML page, here is my code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < getImage.length; i++) {
   $("#a1").append("<img src=\"" + getImage(images[i])+" \"width=\"90\""); 
      }
```

The `getImage` function returns an image...My question, how can I with `JavaScript` or `Jquery` in each iteration  change the attribute of that current line, for example changing `width` or any image attribute of that current line in my `getImage` function . If I use `$('this')` it returns the object, but not in reference to that current line. Can I change those things in every iteration inside that function? so as a result I would get:

```
<img src="1.jpg" width="20">
<img src="2.jpg" width="90" >
```

---

```
function getImage(i) {
// some code

// WANT TO CHANGE HERE THE IMG ATTRIBUTE OF <img src "" width="">
return image ;
}
```

The idea of course is to change many more attributes...

Comment: `$("#a1").append("<img src=\"getImage(images[i])+" \"width=\"90\""); ` Should not it be like `$("#a1").append("<img src=\"" + getImage(images[i])+" \"width=\"90\"");` ?

Comment: Yea,copied it wrong...fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to change the image attributes from within `getImage` then you should not use string-concatenation to build the image-tag.

Try something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  $("#a1").append(getImage(images[i])); 
}
```

with:

```
function getImage(input) {
   var $img = $('<img>').attr({
     src: '%your-source%', // maybe from input?!
     width: 100
   });

   // do other stuff with $img as needed

   return $img;
}
```

Comment: I like this sulution,It makes more sense...just to be sure it only diffrent because here you return $object and in the other solutions you return string? its' not the same perfonmace and abillty?

Comment: I'm using the jQuery object (`$img`) as it's more flexible than strings. If that's your question?

Comment: yea I understand that its jQuery object...but in my case the string solutions also works,where exactly you have more flexibility here? What more I can do with that?

Comment: Well, suppose you'd return a string, but would want to attach an event listener. For this jQuery would need to parse the string again.

Comment: What you mean by "jQuery would need to parse the string again"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as you have it now. As far as I understand, `getImage` simply returns an URL to an image. And it can't modify width of img tag. You can do it like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < getImage.length; i++) {
  $("#a1").append("<img src=\"" + getImage(images[i]) + " \"width=\"" + images[i].width + "\""); 
}
```

assuming that your `images` array contains objects with fields `src` and `width`

Or you should make your getImage return whole `img` tag HTML:

```
for (var i = 0; i < getImage.length; i++) {
      $("#a1").append(getImage(images[i])); 
    }
function getImage(index) {
    // some code
    return "<img src=\"" + image + " \"width=\"" + width + "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have some mistakes but i just want to share an idea of how you could do this in another way.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < getImage.length; i++) {
      $("#a1").append(getImage(images[i])); 
      }

    function getImage(i) {
       var s = // get the src
       var w = // width based on i 
       return "<img src=\"" + s+ " \"width=\"" + w+ "\"" ;
    }
```